# Differentiating a standard normal cumulative distribution function

Tags: derivatives, cumulative-distribution-functions, leibniz-integral-rule

I am trying to find a way to differentiate the standard normal cumulative distribution function. I think it has something to do with the Leibniz rule but I can't wrap my head around it.

I would like to differentiate N(y) in respect to y, where N(.) denotes the standard normal CDF:
$$\frac{d}{dy}N(y) $$
So I think the initial I'd start from the below?
$$ \frac{d}{dy}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^ye^{\frac{-x^2}2}dx $$

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: It follows immediately from the fundamental theorem of calculus https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus